# Selecting item with additional settings from list

Tags: forms, lists, selection, settings

This is for a web interface.

I have a list where users can select items that displays data onto a page. Some items are already preconfigured so that when you select them, no additional settings are required and the data is displayed.

However, some items (such as Item Five in this example) require additional settings to be configured before the data can be displayed. As such, when you select the item another window will appear to apply the settings.

Is there a better way to do this? Having some items preset and others that require configuration in one list doesn't seem like the correct thing to do, but at the same time I'm unable to have these items in a separate list from the presets.

Any suggestions?

[image: List items]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the interaction more clear and easy for users. So users shoud understand the difference in items, which ones are preseted and which ones are needed to be setted up.

Some improvements are:

1. Items, which need to be setted should be clear differentiated, as they requires much efforts to setup. If it's possible, order the items in a way, when presets are at the top of the list. So user travels from "easiest" items to more complex ones.
2. Use pop-up modal dialog for settings. Pop-up allows to separate the setting task, still context remains visible.
3. Use the means for easy exiting, like Cancel button and Esc shortcut.

[image]